# What irritates me is "going" vs. "go" vs. "to go" to school in the morning

Tags: clauses, gerund-vs-infinitive, clefts

I have a problem with using "what clause". Which of following   sentences is correct?

> 1. What irritates me is going to school in early morning
> 2. What irritates me is to go to school in early morning
> 3. what irritates me is go to school in early morning

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you show the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5039) you have done?

Answer (score 2):

Hamid,  I understand your question means: "which of these sentences would be used by a person who spoke English as his first language"?

The answer is "None of them"

A native English speaker (in the UK, Eire, Australia and New Zealand) would say
"What irritates me is going to school early in THE morning"   or
"What irritates me is HAVING to go to school early in THE morning"

I think the same is probably true for North America and other countries where English is the primary language, but I have not lived in those countries so I am not going to assert that is true.

The critical phrase is "in early morning".  You must say "early in THE morning" or "in THE early morning".   I do not know why English speakers add "THE" - it is just the way the language is used

eg
"What irritates me is going to school early in THE morning"

"What makes me happy is coming home from school early in THE afternoon"

"What excites me is going to the cinema in THE evening"

"I have been at school for all of THE day"  or

"I have been at school all day",            but not

"I have been at school for all day"

(My background is that I'm 62, born in England and have lived in the UK, New Zealand and Australia)

Comment: Thank you for you helping. But I have seen a sentence as " what I want to do is to go to cinema ". In this sentence after " tobe" used infinitive in stead of gerund.   Can you help me?